# MySQL: Search for a field, then replace another field in the same row

Tags: mysql

Sorry if the question is stupid but I'm newbie to MySQL and got stuck with this.

Let's suppose I have the following table in MySQL:

**City.........Country.....Restaurants**
Rome......Italy.............3032
Paris.......France........5220

I want to search for the city "Paris" and update the field "Restaurants" (replace 5220 with 5300).

What would be the right MySQL query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UPDATE table SET Restaurants=5300 WHERE City='Paris'`

You could also add `AND Restaurants=5220` to the `WHERE` clause to be even more specific.

Comment: What an incredible site is this! Just found it and got an answer in five minutes! You are awesome! Thanks for the instant reply!!!

Comment: @Francisco - No problem. Just be sure to mark your question as answered so that others can learn.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

```
UPDATE table SET Restaurants = 5300 WHERE city = 'Paris'
```

Keep in mind that if these values (5300 or Paris) are coming from the user, you should make sure to sanitize them. Or better yet, use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html).

Comment: What an incredible site is this! Just found it and got an answer in five minutes! You are awesome! Thanks for the instant reply!!!